# ARCore Unity - Tracked object (Video) Not scaling to Image Target correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

So been racking my brains about how to link content be it 3D, 2D or just sound to trigger when an image is detected using ARCore as would like to add some spatial options down the line. Atm different videos play when different images are detected however they dont conform to the proportions of the image being detected either being too small or elongated out of bounds.

Anything look wrong with this code...

Two C# files were made one called:
AugmentedImageController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleARCore;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class AugmentedImageController : MonoBehaviour {
   [SerializeField] private AugmentedimageVisualizer _augmentedimageVisualizer;

private readonly Dictionary<int, AugmentedimageVisualizer> _visualizers = new Dictionary<int, AugmentedimageVisualizer>();

private readonly List<AugmentedImage> _images = new List<AugmentedImage>();

private void Update()
{
    if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
    {
        return;
    }

    Session.GetTrackables(_images, TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);
    VisualizeTrackables();
}
private void VisualizeTrackables()
{
    foreach (var image in _images)
    {
        var visualizer = GetVisualizer(image);

        if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking && visualizer == null)
        {
            AddVisualizer(image);
        }
        else if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Stopped && visualizer != null)
        {
            RemoveVisualizer(image, visualizer);
        }
    }
}

private void RemoveVisualizer(AugmentedImage image, AugmentedimageVisualizer visualizer)
{
    _visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
    Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);
}

private void AddVisualizer(AugmentedImage image)
{
    var anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
    var visualizer = Instantiate(_augmentedimageVisualizer, anchor.transform);
    visualizer.Image = image;
    _visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);
}

private AugmentedimageVisualizer GetVisualizer(AugmentedImage image)
{
    AugmentedimageVisualizer visualizer;
    _visualizers.TryGetValue(image.DatabaseIndex, out visualizer);
    return visualizer;
}
}
```

Second AugmentedimageVisualizer

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using GoogleARCore;
using GoogleARCoreInternal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public class AugmentedimageVisualizer : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField] private VideoClip[] _videoClips;
  public AugmentedImage Image;
  private VideoPlayer _videoPlayer;

 void Start()
{
    _videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    _videoPlayer.loopPointReached += OnStop;
}

private void OnStop(VideoPlayer source)
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Image == null || Image.TrackingState != TrackingState.Tracking)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!_videoPlayer.isPlaying)
    {
        _videoPlayer.clip = _videoClips[Image.DatabaseIndex];
        _videoPlayer.Play();
    }

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(Image.ExtentX, Image.ExtentZ, 1);
}
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also share your _augmentedimageVisualizer prefab. Probably problem is there. You scale the instance of _augmentedimageVisualizer prefab but what does it look like? You have a plane or a mesh which has the video player component?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the answer already, but in case someone else looks into this i throw out solution of some sort.

U should throw all that sample garbage away. and when you're left only with essential stuff  the image.extentx? i beleive gives u the approximate width of the image in meters. then use that value with some sort of scalar so u get the proper width.